# Very strange issue with asyncore.py

Tags: python-3.x, asyncore

When I try to run a python (3.4.3) program I wrote on Windows, I get the following error message repeated many times, until a maximum recursion depth error occurs:

```
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\asyncore.py", line 411, in __getattr__
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\asyncore.py", line 411, in __getattr__
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\asyncore.py", line 411, in __getattr__
retattr = getattr(self.socket, attr)
retattr = getattr(self.socket, attr)
```

I did a google search, and there was apparently an issue with asyncore.py in Python 3.2 and 3.1 that caused this to happen, but it was supposedly fixed. Even weirder, when I ran this same program on Linux instead, everything worked fine.

What could be a possible cause of this error?

Answer (score 1):

The usual cause of these errors in Python is overriding the attribute lookup. There are two attributes on python classes for this: [**getattr**](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) and [**getattribute**](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__).

When `self.__getattribute__` isn't defined, when an attribute on a class isn't found, `self.__getattr__` is called, and whatever it ends up returning is what is used for the value. However, when `self.__getattribute__` is defined, Python will call that straight off, and it's up to `self.__getattribute__` method to return something sensible.

With either method, it's possible to have a case where `__getattr__`/`__getattribute__` keeps referencing attributes on `self` that don't exist, and `__getattr__`/`__getattribute__` is then called again and again until ultimately Python runs out of stack space.